# set value on textfield from header

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my application I want set textfield value dynamically coming from header. Here is the code

in android project I set on header latitude ang longitude and I am trying get this on rails view.

```
public static String getAddress(final String dir_atoken, final String data_atoken, final float lat, final float lng) throws Exception {

        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.4:3000/address/lookup");

        get.setHeader(LAT,String.valueOf(lat));
        get.setHeader(LNG,String.valueOf(lng));


        return getResponse(get, 200, true);
    }
```

this is my lookup_address controller

```
def lookup_address
    @lat = request.headers['Lat']
    @lng = request.headers['Lng']
  end
```

this is my lookup_address.html.erb

```
<% form_for @location do |f| %>
    <%=  f.error_messages %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :latitude %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :latitude, :value => request.headers['Lat'] %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :longitude %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :longitude, :value => request.headers['Lng'] %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

When I set `:value =>request.headers['Lat']` it always return null.

What should I do here for not getting null value?

Comment: Why are you using `lat` and `lng` as headers; shouldn't they be parameters?

Comment: bcoz I store this on header. the only way to get this is request.headers

Comment: In fact, parameters seem the best tool for what you are looking to accomplish. What exactly do you want the server to give/do for your Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the `@location` is built? Guess it will be more correct to set `@location.latitude` and `@location.longitude` in controller.

```
def lookup_address
  @location = Location.new #Not sure how you build the @location
  @location.latitude = request.headers['Lat']
  @location.longitude = request.headers['Lng']
end
```

lookup_address.html.erb

```
<% form_for @location do |f| %>
    <%=  f.error_messages %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :latitude %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :longitude %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```